# Is there any Systematic/Organic relationship between Accounts on the Network/Ledgers?

Tags: assets, accounts, payments

I wonder if there's an organic relationship between an Account that Creates other Accounts on the Ledger or not?
Assume we have an Institution with a couple of Board Members, each have an Account of their own.
When we attemp to create an Asset and offer it to the public, it's Issuing-Account (with it's own Signer(s), Options e.g. "Weights/Treshholds" etc.) should create with a Source-Account (according to Stellar documentation, any Account needs to be created by another "Source-Account").
As far I understand, Accounts have no special previledge over other Accounts on the Ledger (Custodial/Hirarchial/...), so is there any difference (from programming/technical perspective) which Account we use as so-called Source-Account for this Operation? or is it just a matter of, let's say our Organizational Structure/Plocies to decide?
Clarify this for me please.

Stay Safe Ya'll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally up to you and you are right when you say the source account has no special privileges.

From a programming / technical perspective it doesn't matter which account you use for the source account. That being said, if you want to keep all of your accounts organized or 'connected' in some way, then you might consider using a specific account.

Comment: To my understanding, if we need to implement some kind of organazional management for Accounts and their hirarchy, we need to apply a proprietary scheme and manage such information in our local database.